# Unknown JavaScript syntax before for...in

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book about single-page applications and at some point there is this for...in loop:

```
KEYVAL:
for(key_name in arg_map){
    if(arg_map.hasOwnProperty(key_name)){
        if(key_name.indexOf('_') === 0) continue KEYVAL;

        anchor_map_revise[key_name] = arg_map[key_name];

        key_name_dep = '_' + key_name;
        if(arg_map[key_name_dep]){
            anchor_map_revise[key_name_dep] = arg_map[key_name_dep];
        }
        else{
            delete anchor_map_revise[key_name_dep];
            delete anchor_map_revise['_s' + key_name_dep];
        }
    }
}
```

What really caught my eye was the `KEYVAL` word right before the loop. Is it a variable? What does it represent? What is it for? What does this syntax mean? The word only appears in the two places in the included code and never again in the whole example.

I've been searching a lot trying to figure this out, but so far I have not been able to find any information. Could someone please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) :-)

Comment: shouldn't KEYVAL: be at the end of the block? I guess, being before the for(), it looks like it would reset the for loop, leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: @Paul - no label does that by default -- labels are used to go before, exactly why they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KEYVAL:` is a label here which is used in your loop for iteration the operations. Look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

It is similar to GOTO statements.

What it does in your code is  when this condition become true

```
if(key_name.indexOf('_') === 0) continue KEYVAL;
```

its go to the label `KEYVAL:` and run the loop again without executing the code below this line.

Answer (score 2):

It is a `label`, sort of a line-number but not locked to a line position.

Continue jumps to this label like a GOTO.

When this criteria is furfilled:

```
if(key_name.indexOf('_') === 0) continue KEYVAL;
```

JavaScript continues from that label above.

Answer (score 1):

It is for break and continue.

Check the MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label